# Is this really the kind of site we want?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rationale behind closing a useful question with 70K views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85963/whats-the-rationale-behind-closing-a-useful-question-with-70k-views)

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago) — locked as “divisive” — and ask yourself if it really impossible to have a civil discussion on this topic, which was *clearly* popular and useful to exactly this community (programmers).

In fact, the only real *opportunity for division* I see here would be the question, “omg who gets the official ‘accepted’ tick mark?” which, really, should *not* be a serious concern. Karma shouldn’t be driving the site to the point where useful, popular discussions are essentially *banned*.

Is the problem just the type of people who are users here? Is everyone so arrogant they can’t even deal with open-ended questions whatsoever?

Is this simply a niche you want Quora to own?

Or are the mods clueless?

I’m baffled, honestly.

Comment: It should have been closed a long time ago