# Allow new comments to be moved into an existing "move to chat" chatroom

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, moderator-tools

Note: this is an alternative proposal to [Make "Move to Chat" automatic, moving all comments. Direct all further comments to the chat room and enable OP notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287576/make-move-to-chat-automatic-moving-all-comments-direct-all-further-comments)

> The manner in which comments are moved to chat on "noisy" websites is
>   incredibly disruptive.  It goes something like this:
>
> 1. Several comments are moved to chat by a moderator and linked to the chat room.
> 2. More comments are written under the post.
> 3. Moderator returns and deletes all of the new comments, leaving a new comment "Comments cannot be moved to chat twice.  Any further
>      comments will be deleted."
>
> The workflow for moving comments to chat is very haphazard.  You never
>   know when the "would you like to move this conversation to chat" link
>   will appear, and when it does, it doesn't actually *move* the
>   comments, nor does it "move" all of them.  This is also true of
>   moderator chat conversions.
>
> The policy of deleting further comments because they can't be moved
>   into the chatroom is just terrible in so many ways.

Several mods have expressed an interest in retaining better control over this process.  Therefore, I suggest that we **allow diamond moderators to move new comments to an existing "move to chat" chatroom** (preserving time order).

Comment: Hmm, people like this better I guess.

Comment: Those *new* comments would all appear as one batch in the transcript, right? Not fancy stuff to insert them with respect to the timeline?

Comment: @rene: My suggestion would be insertion in time order (which will still put the comments at the end of the transcript, 95 percent of the time).  Doing it any other way wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: In 5 percent it would be highly confusing ...

Comment: Not if it's in time order.  It's basically a merge.

Comment: I think this is the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266693/could-mods-have-add-comments-to-chat-to-supplement-move-comments-to-chat?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Jefromi: Great post, but nothing much seems to be happening there, other than a lot of upvotes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, sure - the point is, I don't think there's much to discuss here, since the idea seems to already have overwhelming support (upvotes, nobody voicing concerns). We just need SE to respond.

Comment: dupe target apparently lacks bounties